# Phpunit method @depends not receiving

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

Can somebody explain me why the method 'testGetUniqueUser' is receiving nothing as argument from the method it depends ? or how can I pass it an argument coming from another method ? All I'm trying to accomplish is as soon a user is created, I do a GET request to verify if this one exist.

```
/**
 * @depends ::testPostUser201
 * @param int $id
 */
public function testGetUniqueUser(int $id)
{

    self::$client->request(
        request::METHOD_GET,
        UserController::USER_API_PATH . "/" . $id
    );

    /** @var Response $response */
    $response = self::$client->getResponse();
    self::assertEquals(
        Response::HTTP_OK, $response->getStatusCode()
    );
    $dataResponse = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
    self::assertArrayHasKey('user', $dataResponse);
}

/**
 * @covers ::postUser
 * @return int
 */
public function testPostUser201(): int
{
    $data = [
        'username' => 'ener',
        'email' => 'dgor@live.com',
        'password' => 'memories',
        'enable' => 'true'
    ];

    self::$client->request(
        Request::METHOD_POST,
        UserController::USER_API_PATH,
        [], [], [], json_encode($data)
    );
    /** @var Response $response */
    $response = self::$client->getResponse();
    self::assertEquals(
        Response::HTTP_CREATED,
        $response->getStatusCode()
    );
    $dataResponse = json_decode($response->getContent(), true);
    $id = $dataResponse['id'];
    self::assertArrayHasKey('user', $dataResponse);

    return $id;
}
```

Comment: i believe there is no need in `::` before method name in `@depends` annotatin